# Pyside6 and cx_freeze able to convert to executable file however unable to open

Tags: cx-freeze, pyside6

Version

- PySide6: 6.6.1
- shiboken6: 6.6.1
- cx_Freeze: 6.15.14

My cx_freeze code:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


files = ["music.mp3", "logo.png", "main.ui", "myfolder"]

build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["os"],
    "include_files":files
}

# base="Win32GUI"
base = "Win32GUI" if sys.platform == "win32" else None

setup(
    name="my app",
    version="1.0",
    description="my app",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable("main.py", base=base)],
)
```

I follow according to the documentation provided (https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/deployment/deployment-cxfreeze.html). I keep facing this error:
[image: Error Image]

i try copy change it to file by adding a the dll file

```
files = ["music.mp3", "logo.png", "main.ui", "myfolder" ,"..\myenv\Lib\site-packages\shiboken6\shiboken6.abi3.dll"]
```

But i still keep getting the same error any idea of how to fix this or is there another way i could freeze my pyside6 file with all the require folder

Comment: I've never used cx_freeze with PySide, but, in any case, Shiboken is not *just a file*, it's a **library**, meaning that it should be added as such. According to the [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/script.html#cmdoption-packages), it should be used with the `packages` flag or related config option. There is a **huge** difference between including a file as resource and a shared library.

Comment: @musicamante i follow according to the documentation u have comment, and change my build_exe_options to this `build_exe_options = {

"zip_include_packages": ["encodings", "PySide6"],
    "packages": ["os", "shiboken6"],
    "include_files":files
}` and i still face the same issue any idea? and mind sharing what other library u use to turn ur pyside6 application into an exe file

Comment: I've only built PyQt4/5 apps, so, sorry, but I cannot really help you on the Py...Side.